# M Power Query - Expand Columns Dynamically

Tags: json, powerquery

I'm trying to expand columns after converting to a table, but these columns need to be expanded dynamically.

I've researched online but the code I'm adding just does not work one way or another. I must be missing something but i am not sure.

This is my code:

```
let
Date = DateTime.ToText((DateTime.LocalNow()), "yyyy-MM-dd"),
Date2 = Date.ToText((Date.AddDays(Date.From(DateTime.FixedLocalNow()),-90)), "yyyy-MM-dd"),
Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://www.findmyshift.com/staff-view?r=2rr67u5y9i&apikey=***********&format=json&start=" & Date2 & "&finish=" & Date)),
#"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
#"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", List.Accumulate(#"Converted to Table"[Column1], {}, (state, current) => List.Union({state, Table.ColumnNames(current)}))),
#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Expanded Column1","&#39;","'",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Column1.Name"}),
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.TransformColumnNames(#"Replaced Value", (columnName as text) as text => Text.Replace(columnName, "Column1.", ""))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should remove your API key from your question, you probably don't want people to misuse/access this service using your credentials. (It might be good to ask the service provider to issue you a new API key as replacement, so that nobody can use the one in your answer.)

If you replace `"REPLACE ME WITH YOUR API KEY"` (in the code below) with your actual API key (between double quotes), then this code should do what you were trying to do.

```
let
    startDate = Date.ToText((Date.AddDays(Date.From(DateTime.FixedLocalNow()),-90)), "yyyy-MM-dd"),
    endDate = DateTime.ToText((DateTime.LocalNow()), "yyyy-MM-dd"),
    jsonResponse =
        let
            response = Web.Contents("https://www.findmyshift.com/staff-view", [Query = [r = "2rr67u5y9i", apikey = "REPLACE ME WITH YOUR API KEY", format = "json", start = startDate, finish = endDate]]),
            json = Json.Document(response)
        in
            json,
    toTable = Table.FromRecords(jsonResponse),
    replaceValue = Table.ReplaceValue(toTable, "&#39;", "'", Replacer.ReplaceText, Table.ColumnNames(toTable)) // Replace in all columns
in
    replaceValue
```

- `Table.FromRecords` can do what you were trying to do (without all the dynamic column expanding and renaming)
- `Web.Contents` can build the query string for you (and will automatically handle URL encoding) provided you pass an argument to the `Query` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace step **#"Expanded Column1"** by following code:

```
= Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1",
Record.FieldNames(#"Converted to Table"{0}[Column1]))
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but i get an error message:

**Expression.Error: We cannot convert a value of type Record to type Table.**

Comment: This error actually appeared with your initial code, but after replacement, which I suggested, all works fine. So you could try again: